# Is it possible to write an Enigma encryption algorithm that can use all alphanumeric as input but does not output ambiguous characters?

Tags: encryption

This is about Enigma encryption, I'm guessing the number of rotors doesn't matter but I'm using 3.

I am working with what's basically a coded version of the old mechanical enigma style encryption machines.  The concept is rather old but before I get too far into learning it, I was wondering if it would be possible to be able to encrypt using all characters 0-9 a-z and A-Z but the encrypted text itself will only be a subset of these characters?  I'm trying to replace a subset of characters (around 10 total) from the encrypted output, while still being able to get back to those characters if they were part of the input?

Comment: Yes, you're describing a set of one-to-one mappings generated by a "key".

Comment: In general, yes ofcourse: you could always create a multi character result value, having a bijective (1 to 1) relation with the actual input character set. In the end it's all numbers, so creating your own representation is not that hard.... in theory ;-)

Comment: I don't understand how I can have 1 to 1 mappings if I have 61 input characters but am limited to 51 output characters.  That's a many to one that I don't know how to get back from.  I've considered Stefan's approach but I'm not sure what I think about doubling the length of the already long key.

Comment: It is still possible, you just have to sacrifice string length e.g. 10 chars input might encrypt to 12 chars.  Otherwise though, you can't go from a charset of 61 -> 51 in length **and** retain the same string length.

Comment: I got it now, thanks Luke, Stefan, and Andrew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disambiguate by adding 1 to 2-character mapping for ambiguous symbols: O -> A1; 0 -> A2; other ambiguous symbols; A->AA. This is basically just like escaping in strings: we usually can’t put new line inside the string, so we represent it as \n. \ is represented as \\

If you’re working with encrypted data (so the probabilities of all characters are uniformly distributed and characters cannot be predicted) then you can’t compress the ciphertext. If you can compress it, then you’ve noticed some kind of pattern in the text and partially broken the encryption.

If you want to reduce the ciphertext’s alphabet, then you must increase the length of the ciphertext, otherwise you’ve successfully compressed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was an approach I looked at. I ended up doing some binary conversions to another base and reduced my output to a certain set of uppercase letters. Turns out everyone really liked it so we stuck with it.  Your final sentence is something I realized before deciding to do a 1-2 character mapping approach like this, but I had a light bulb go off the other day to make this much simpler to code (the constrictions on length of the final text weren't as important as I thought). I selected it as the answer because I believe this is a great approach.